# Strange Behaviour for “Stack Overflow” query on google.co.in

Tags: support, google

For query "Stack overflow" in Google why it is showing first result from www.doioig.gov website. I can see first results snippet and Title same as stackoverflow.com but only URL is www.doioig.gov. Please check out at google.co.in and let me know the reason.

[image: Reproduced]

Comment: Reproduced from Israel. It's not a localized issue.

Comment: I'm not seeing the same behavior on google.com, but if I search doioig in google.com, the first result says "Stack Overflow" but the snippet and url are from doioig.gov

Comment: and the UK from google.co.uk... and France from google.fr

Comment: easily reproducible with phrase search on google.co.in or google.com.au as "stack overflow""